# IEnumerable<T> and reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-2.0, ienumerable

**Background**

Working in .NET 2.0 Here, reflecting lists in general. I was originally using `t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable))` to detect if a Property I was traversing supported the `IEnumerable` Interface. (And thus I could cast the object to it safely)

However this code was not evaluating to `True` when the object is a `BindingList<T>`.

**Next**

I tried to use `t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable))` and didn't have any luck either.

**Code**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reflects an enumerable (not a list, bad name should be fixed later maybe?)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o">The Object the property resides on.</param>
    /// <param name="p">The Property We're reflecting on</param>
    /// <param name="rla">The Attribute tagged to this property</param>
    public void ReflectList(object o, PropertyInfo p, ReflectedListAttribute rla)
    {
        Type t = p.PropertyType;
        //if (t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable)))
        if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable)))
        {
            IEnumerable e = p.GetValue(o, null) as IEnumerable;

            int count = 0;
            if (e != null)
            {
                foreach (object lo in e)
                {
                    if (count >= rla.MaxRows)
                        break;

                    ReflectObject(lo, count);

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Intent**

I want to basically tag lists i want to reflect through with the `ReflectedListAttribute` and call this function on the properties that has it. (Already Working)

Once inside this function, given the object the property resides on, and the `PropertyInfo` related, get the value of the property, cast it to an IEnumerable (assuming it's possible) and then iterate through each child and call `ReflectObject(...)` on the child with the count variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do the `as IEnumerable` and the variable is not null you know that it does implement `IEnumerable` interface.

You don´t need the code:

```
Type t = p.PropertyType;
//if (t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable)))
if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable)))
{
```

This would be enough:

```
public void ReflectList(object o, PropertyInfo p, ReflectedListAttribute rla)
{
    IEnumerable e = p.GetValue(o, null) as IEnumerable;

    int count = 0;
    if (e != null)
    {
        foreach (object lo in e)
        {
            if (count >= rla.MaxRows)
                break;
            ReflectObject(lo, count);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is what happens when you return to old code when you discover you mocked it up long ago and it doesn't work. Now that you mention it, I haven't the foggiest idea how i missed that >_<. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)

> The IsSubclassOf method cannot be used
>   to determine whether an interface
>   derives from another interface, or
>   whether a class implements an
>   interface  Use the GetInterface method for that purpose

Also your implementation of IsAssignableFrom is wrong, you should use it like this:

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(t)
```

This should return true if IEnumerable is implemented by t..

Answer (score 3):

Why do you the if-statement at all?

You already did a `var e = ... as IEnumerable` and afterwards just check if is not null.

Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1):

These work. :)

A `List` is extended `Collection`. So, the tests are different for them. A `Dictionary` has got two internal containers. Hence one test for the same.

```
public static bool IsList(object obj)
{
    System.Collections.IList list = obj as System.Collections.IList;
    return list != null;
}

public static bool IsCollection(object obj)
{
    System.Collections.ICollection coll = obj as System.Collections.ICollection;
    return coll != null;
}

public static bool IsDictionary(object obj)
{
    System.Collections.IDictionary dictionary = obj as System.Collections.IDictionary;
    return dictionary != null;
}
```

Usage example -

```
if (IsDictionary(fieldObject)) //key-value type collection?
{
    System.Collections.IDictionary dictionary = fieldObject as System.Collections.IDictionary;
    foreach (object _ob in dictionary.Values)
    {
        //do work
    }
    // dictionary.Clear();
}
else //normal collection
{
    if (IsCollection(fieldObject))
    {
        System.Collections.ICollection coll = fieldObject as System.Collections.ICollection;
        foreach (object _ob in coll)
        {
            //do work
        }

        if (IsList(fieldObject))
        {
            //System.Collections.IList list = fieldObject as System.Collections.IList;
            //list.Clear(); // <--- List's function, not Collection's.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using that pattern, as it does redundant casts. It is expected to do a null check after using "as", this results in simpler code (no extra method call needed) and a single cast (see Jens answer).

Comment: I understand. These are functions I posted, for re-usability purpose. Jens method does simplify these by in-lining the code, but also provides space for duplicates. OP gets to choose, now.